# DC voltage source in series with AC voltage

Tags: transformer, ac, dc

I am a bit confused with this circuit.

Assuming "i_x" is the left side current of circuit without the 3V DC source.

In steady state is i1(t)=(3/200)+i_x?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Yes, the DC current flowing through the primary-side loop is 15mA. The AC current caused by Vs(t) is added on top of it.

A circuit made entirely from passive elements and independent sources is linear and time-invariant (LTI), which means that the superposition principle holds for arbitrary linear combinations (weighted sums) of DC and AC signals of any frequency. Therefore, you can calculate the contribution of each source to the currents flowing through the circuit individually, and then add them up.

In particular, the inductor and transformer primary are short-circuits at DC, making it possible to easily calculate the DC current flowing through the primary-side loop without taking the secondary side into account.

Comment: Just to add a bit: _at AC_, a DC source gets set to zero -- that means that a voltage source looks like a wire, and a current source looks like an open circuit.  Ditto, at DC, the AC source gets set to zero (short or open circuit, depending on what type it is).